# Select top balance per branch, only ONE per branch

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database based on a bank, each branch having a Unique branch ID.

I am trying to create a query showing the top balance from the savings accounts at each branch. Only showing ONE row per branch ID.

I have this query which shows the top balances of savings accounts but I cannot figure out how to have this unique per branch ID.

```
select max(a.balance) as balance, b.bid, c.pname.firstname, c.pname.middleinitial, c.pname.lastname
from brancht b
join accountt a on b.bid=a.bid
join customeraccountt ca on ca.accnum = a.accnum
join customert c on c.custid = ca.custid
where acctype='Savings'
group by b.bid, c.pname.firstname, c.pname.middleinitial, c.pname.lastname
order by balance desc, b.bid
/
```

The results for this query returns this:

```
BALANCE      BID   PNAME.FIRSTNAME    PNAME.MIDDLEINITIAL PNAME.LASTNAME 

14050        101   Kornelia           J                   Oconnor             
13000        101   Myra               D                   Johnson 
9850         105   Lucie              M                   Crosby              
9050         105   Simon              R                   Patrick
```

Another part of the query would be to also show their limit of overdraft on their current accounts (if they have one) if it's possible to have that in the same query?

Hopefully this is enough information.

Comment: You are grouping by more than just the branch ID. That's why you are having more than one row per branch ID

Comment: I believed if the select statement had max() you must group by all other columns? SQLDeveloper forces that you group by the other columns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try using ROW_NUMBER function as below. In the sub-query a ROW_NUMBER is assigned to each row based on balance partitioned by Branch. Row with maximum balance for a particular branch will be assigned 1 and so on ; Then you filter only those records having row_number -1 ; Each branch will have only one record (maximum balance) with ROW_NUMBER=1

```
select * from 
(select balance, b.bid, c.pname.firstname, c.pname.middleinitial, c.pname.lastname,
row_number() over (partion by b.bid order by balance desc) as rn
from brancht b
join accountt a on b.bid=a.bid
join customeraccountt ca on ca.accnum = a.accnum
join customert c on c.custid = ca.custid
where acctype='Savings'
group by b.bid, c.pname.firstname, c.pname.middleinitial, c.pname.lastname
) where rn=1
```

Comment: SQLDeveloper doesn't allow this query. Says there is a missing parenthesis at (partion... Partion is being descried as a partially recognized rule (railroad diagram) followed by order by clauses etc?

Comment: Oh sorry yes there was a couple of typos but got it working, thank you very much!